# Unable to see subtlte in Tizen TV

Tags: tizen, tizen-web-app, tizen-emulator, tizen-studio

I have a Tizen TV of 2015 model and I developed an application for video streaming.

Every video has embedded CC but when I play it on my TV after enabling cc from TV **Menu>>System>>Accessibility>>Subtitle>>ON** but video is not displaying subtitle(CC).

When I play same video URL in web browser then it is displaying CC.

I also submitted this app on Tizen store and Tizen TV store QA also able to see CC in my app.

Please help me to see Subtitle.

Comment: So Tizen Store QA saw your app better then you did. You lucky...

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue with tizen, for some reason tizen can't read subtitles from .m3u file.

While everything worked fine in android and ios application, tizen and webos were unable to get subtitles from .m3u files.

Unfortunately until today we haven't found solution for this issue.

I know that this doesn't solve your problem, but I also know how hard is to find help when working with tizen, community is not that big and Samsung support is wery slow and not too helpful...

At least now you know that you're not alone :)

I think that the best way to solve this issue is to use some third party player like https://github.com/google/shaka-player or https://videojs.com